# Problem with TcpListener on Silverlight application

Tags: c#, silverlight-3.0

I am writing silverlight 3 application which is working on network.
It works like client-server application. There is WinForm application for server and silverlight application for client.
I use TcpListener  on server and connect from client to it with Socket.
In local network it works fine, but when I try to use it from internet it don't connect to server.
I use IP address on local network and real IP with port number for internet version.
Where is the problem?
Thanks.

Comment: whats the exact error message you got??

Comment: socket's Connceted property return false

Comment: Many possibilities that could affect connectivity. Do you control the network infrastructure for the public server? If not, do you use a standard port or a port that is not blocked by a firewall? When hosting somewhere, even Root servers are often guarded by default and ports must explicitly being opened (either via config tool or service call) to connect in other than originally meant ways. As to help you further I agree with Ramesh, there's a need to have more information.

Comment: firewall is turned off, and port is opened, I open my page with real IP and port number, not from URL, I dont get any exception or error message, the only thing can say is that Connected property return false. I don't know how to see errors. If there any property or something else please from wich I can get the error please say and I will try to give you more informaion.
Thanks.

Comment: I got error message. It says 'access denied'. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in my computer. It connected to local network, which is connected to router.
Thats why I can't connect to my computer.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know in Silverlight you have so use a port in the range 4502-4534, and a policy file should be on the server machine to allow the connection to be made. I wouldn't be surprised if local network connections are allowed in some cases.

I'm not too familiar with Silverlight 3 though, See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645032(VS.95).aspx for more information.

If you can see the policy file being GET in the HTTP access log, you might be able to break the problem in two.

Edited: Text changed because at first for some reason I thought you said you tested on "localhost".